# How do I get a cumulative sum using cumsum in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cumsum

This is code

```
for i = 1 : 5
    b = i;
    a=cumsum(b);

end

fprintf('%f \n', a);
```

I expected 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 so I would print 15 at the end.

But it output 5.000000.

If i code "a = cumsum (b)" outside the for loop, it will not be calculated

How can I get the value I want 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` performs something like integration, where each element of the output is the sum of all elements up to that position (including) of the input vector.

Your code doesn't work because you pass a single value into `cumsum` and there is no mechanism by which the previous result is saved, so you end up having only a single value, which is the last one - `5`.

You don't need a loop for this, nor even `cumsum` - just write `sum(1:5)` to get the desired result.

Comment: thsnk you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `cumsum` works. It takes the cumulative sum of an array the example below may explain better

```
a = 1:5;
b = cumsum(a); % b = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
c = sum(a) % add up all the elements c = 15
```

Does that help?